# souin cache, revalidating cached objects in the background while serving stale ones

Tags: caching, traefik, cache-control, stale-while-revalidate

im a web dev trying to improve TTFB performance on websites which tolerate serving stale content.
I try to configure something similar to [vercels incremental static regeneration](https://vercel.com/docs/incremental-static-regeneration) or similarly the `stale-while-revalidate` cache-control header in http.

The idea is to initially fetch the upstream response and then subsequently serve the stale cached response. **but once the cached object becomes stale the cache layer should still serve the stale content while fetching the fresh content upstream in the background**.

I currently use traefik as a reverse proxy and a caching layer provided by [souin](https://github.com/darkweak/souin). that is why my question is souin specific.

My current cache-control response headers are `public, max-age=120, stale-while-revalidate=3600` and i would expect souin to interpret it so the content is treated as fresh for 2m and serving stale responses while refetching asynchronously for 1h.
But souin ignores the stale-while-revalidate strategy so I assume it is not implemented in the cache layer and expected to be used as a client caching strategy only.

I don't know enough about caching to make headway. If someone could point me in the right direction or resources to read I would be rather thankful.